# update nested array element

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I try to update element inside of the nested array like below

```
'_id': 1
'products': [
        {'sku': 'cnx1cs', 
         'name': 'abc',
         'specs':[
            {“aaa”: 30,   “bbb”: 2},
                {“aaa”: 40,   “bbb”: 5}
                ]
                   }
        ]
```

When I update it with below command there is no problem

```
db.krm.update({"products.specs.aaa":30},{$set:{"products.0.specs.0.bbb":50}})
```

or update value inside of the first array

```
db.krm.update({"products.specs.aaa":30},{$set:{"products.$.name":"xyz"}})
```

But I have problem when I use $ inside of the code like below

```
db.krm.update({"products.specs.aaa":30},{$set:{"products.$.specs.$.bbb":50}})
```

I got error

```
can't append to array using string field name [$]
```

does is it supported ? or do I make mistake somewhere ?

regards

Comment: No, using multiple `$` positional operators isn't supported.

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831 and there are lots of questions that have the same answer.